# Asymptotics of Green's function for Laplace-Beltrami operator

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory, greens-function

In the following, let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold and $\Delta = \nabla \cdot\nabla $ a Laplace-Beltrami operator on $M$.

Let $G_y(x)$ be Green's function for $\Delta$ (a.k.a fundamental solution for Laplace equation) defined by the condition $$ \Delta G_y(x) = \delta_y(x) - V^{-1},$$ where $V$ is the Riemannian volume of $M$.

It is known that singularity of $G$ is of the same form as in $\mathbb{R}^n$, that is (up to constants)
$$ G_y(x) = u(x, y) + v(x, y),$$
where $u(x, y)=  \begin{cases}
      {d(x,y)}^{2-n}  \text{ for }  n > 2\\
      \log(d(x,y)) \text{ for } n = 2
    \end{cases}$ and $v(x, y)$ is continuous/smooth.

The question is: **is anything known about the asymtotics of $v(x, y)$ in the limit $d(x, y) \rightarrow 0 $?**

I am aware of the expansion of $G_y$ in terms of eigendecomposition of $\Delta$, as well as number of results on bounds for eigenvalues (Cheeger-Yau, Lichnerowicz, ...). However, none of them seem to provide anything about the eigenfunctions, which is what really needed to answer the question.

Comment: Hi, I wonder what is the meaning of this distance, is it the distance on the surface or the distance in euclead space?